# JAVA Program to find largest prime-factor, but the output is wrong?

Tags: java, primes, factors

I have return the code(in Java) to *Find the largest Prime-Factor of a given number*.

I have found checked all the factors and then checked whether it is prime or not.... If so print the largest Prime Factor.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problem3 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.next()); // Takes input from the user.
        int p=0,i,j,max=0,c=0;

        for(i=1;i<n;i++) {
            if(n%i != 0) { //Checks for factors and assigns that value to "c"
                c = i;
                for(j=1;j<c;j++) {
                    if(c%j==0) { //checks for prime number or not, if so... assign that value to "p"
                        p = j;
                    }

                    if(max<p) { // Checks for largest Prime factors, and assigns that value to "max"
                        max = p;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        System.out.println(max); // prints the maximum prime-factor value.
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

I expect the output of 14 to be 7, but the actual output is 1

Comment: I tried for input "13195", and I got "2639" as output.... but 2639 is not a prime number!

Answer (score 1):

You prime check is wrong. `c` is prime only if `c % j != 0` for all 1 < j < c.

```
int max=0,c=0;

for(int i=1;i<n;i++) {
    if(n%i == 0) { //Checks for factors and assigns that value to "c"
        c = i;
        for(int j=2;j<c;j++) {
            if(c%j==0) { // not prime
                c = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(max < c) { // if c > max, it must be > 0, which means it must be prime
            max = c;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(max); // prints the maximum prime-factor value.
```

Comment: Thank you, i didn't see that "Prime Code", but still the answer is getting Wrong... I got "6" for "14".

Comment: @pop I replaced your loop with my loop and got output 7 for input 14.

Comment: Thank you, I got output 7 for input 14, but for another input "30", as per my question, I must get  "5" (as this is the largest Prime-Factor), but the output is "15", which is Not-Prime.

Comment: @pop I'm getting 5 for 30. I don't know which code you are running, but it can't be the code in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number");
    int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.next()); // Takes input from the user.
    int p = 0, i, j, max = 0, c = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) { //Checks for factors and assigns that value to "c"
            c = i;
            if (isPrime(c) && c > max) {
                max = c;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(max); // prints the maximum prime-factor value.
    sc.close();
}

private static boolean isPrime(int num) {
    if (num == 0 || num == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < num / 2; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I tried for input "13195", and I got "2639" as output.... but 2639 is not a prime number!

Comment: @pop I think you tested with the old version. Could you test it again?

Comment: I have tried again on "https://www.onlinegdb.com" (class name must be changed to "Main")and compiled as JAVA program, but the output is Wrong as "2639"

Comment: @pop I checked my code in onlinegdb.com and it gave me expected output which is 29.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be an error in your for loop. I've created a method for this using java 8. try below code,

***Java 8***

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);) {
        System.out.println("Enter the number");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.next()); // Takes input from the user.

        int max = IntStream.range(0, n).filter(q -> isFactor(n, q)).filter(q -> isPrimeNumber(q)).max().getAsInt();

        System.out.println(max); // prints the maximum prime-factor value.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}

public static boolean isPrimeNumber(int n) {
    int i, m = 0, flag = 0;
    m = n / 2;
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        for (i = 2; i <= m; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                flag = 1;
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean isFactor(int n1, int n2) {
    if(n2==0) {
        return false;
    }
    return n1 % n2 == 0;
}
```

***Java 7***

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);) {
        System.out.println("Enter the number");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.next()); // Takes input from the user.

        int max = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (isFactor(n, i)) { // checks for factor
                if (isPrimeNumber(i)) { // checks for prime
                    if (i >= max) { // checks for max number
                        max = i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(max); // prints the maximum prime-factor value.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't do what is asked: it finds the largest prime up to a given limit. This does not mean it is also a factor of that limit. E.g. for `9` it would find `7`, whereas the correct answer would be `3`.

Comment: I've made a mistake. now i fixed that.

Comment: @pop In here intStream act as your for loop. it will loop through 0 to n times. n is the input value. then inside that for there is a if condition checks for the factor. inside that if there is another if which checks for prime number. finally `max().getAsInt()` will return maximum value as integer.